# Linking Images in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to create a dynamic image link (in Laravel 5.0), like this:

```
@foreach($result as $r)
<div>
     <a href="{{URL::to('productdetail?id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>')}}">
     <img src="..\public\uploads\{!! $r->fileName !!}" height="200" width="250"/>
     </a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

and the link it generates is:

```
http://localhost:8000/{{URL::to('productdetail?id=1'}}
```

But I want to generate a link like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/productDetail?id=1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tux almost had it, but you need to put the variable outside the string. This should work:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('productdetail?id='.$r->id) }}">
```

But why are you using a GET variable for this? The beauty of Laravel is that you can have the ID as part of the URL. If I was writing this I would have this in my routes file:

```
Route::get('/product/{stub}/{id}', ['as' => 'prodDetailPage', 'uses' => 'ProductDetail@index');
```

Then you could just use `<a href="{{ route('prodDetailPage', [$r->stub, $r->id]) }}">`

For stub you can create a function to turn the title into a stub, it would need to convert it to lower case, remove special chars and convert spaces to hyphens.

Comment: This is also another way though.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use:

```
@foreach($result as $r)
<div>
     <a href="{{URL::to('productdetail?id=$r->id')}}">
     <img src="..\public\uploads\{!! $r->fileName !!}" height="200" width="250"/>
     </a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I did, but it didn't work, I have got the answer myself, and posted it, u can have a look!

Comment: Cool. Could you share how the url looks after using the code I added? I did try it on my end and worke.  You can use {{ }} which is equivalent to an echo.

Comment: yeah but this way, it echoed `productdetail?id=$r->id` instead of `productdetail?id=1`

Comment: Could you try replacing the single quote with a double quote instead?

`<a href="{{URL::to("productdetail?id=$r->id")}}">`

Comment: @TuxDictumst You can't include `$r->id` in a string like that. If you want to do that you need to wrap it in braces `{{ URL::to("productdetail?id={$r->id}") }}` but it's cleaner to just add it after the string, `{{ URL::to("productdetail?id=".$r->id) }}`

Comment: @Styphon Actually you can but I find your way a lot cleaner. referring to `<a href="{{ URL::to('productdetail?id='.$r->id) }}">`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have got this, actually I was putting the PHP tags at a wrong place, so the final link would be like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="{!! URL::to('productdetail?id=') !!}<?php echo $r->id; ?>">
    <img src="..\public\uploads\{!! $r->fileName !!}" height="200" width="250"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What you've written there is the equivalent of `<a href="<?php echo URL::to('productdetail?id=') ?><?php echo $r->id; ?>">` There's no need for the extra php tag, you can just put it all before the `!!}` closing.